# How can I view all metrics namespace in Kibana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I am streaming AWS metrics to Kibana via `metricsbeat`. When I open `Metrics` in Kibana, I can only see these 4 metrics. But I have configured many metrics set and namespace in metricbeat. Is there any reason it only shows 4? How can I make all metrics available to view?

```
metricsets:
        - cloudwatch
        - lambda
        - billing
      metrics:
        - namespace: AWS/DynamoDB
        - namespace: AWS/Lambda
        - namespace: AWS/Events
        - namespace: AWS/AppSync
        - namespace: AWS/ApiGateway
        - namespace: AWS/RDS
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe there is no data for other metrics?

Comment: There are many of them. I can view them via the raw query